# Android Dagger2 Usage error "depends on more than one scoped component"

Tags: android, dagger-2

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkrZP.png)

I would like to ask how to solve better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GiftsComponent` is defined as `@Component(dependencies={AppComponent.class, LiveDetailComponent.class})` which is a `Singleton` scoped and an `ActivityScoped` component, which is more than one scoped component.

Solution: don't depend on multiple scoped components. (It would be enough for that to depend on `LiveDetailComponent`, if you specify the provision methods in your Component interface then you'll inherit the bindings from the superscopes)